# How to get the output file by running Python file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am beginner of Python user and select Visual Studio Code as editor. Recently I write down one Python file to identify all the files/directory name at the same level with and then output txt files to list down all the files/directory name that match my rule.

I remember in last month, when I run this Python file with Visual Studio Code, the output files will be seen at the parent folder(upper/previous level). But today, there is no output files after running this Python file with Visual Studio Code. Due to this reason, I double click the Python file directly to run it without Visual Studio Code and see the output files at the same level along with my Python file.

So my problems are:

1. How to ensure we can get the output files by running Python file with Visual Studio Code?
2. How to generate the output files at the same level along with Python file that would be run?

Code:

```py
import os

CurrentScriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

All_DirName = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(CurrentScriptDir):    
    for each_dir in dirs:
        All_DirName.append(each_dir)

for Each_DirName in All_DirName:
    Each_DirName_Split = Each_DirName.split('_')
    if Each_DirName_Split[3] == 'twc':
        unitname = "_".join(Each_DirName_Split[0:-1]) 
        with open(unitname + ".txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(Each_DirName + "_K3" + "\n")
        file.close()
    else:
        next
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant portion of the code that writes the output to file, as well as how you are calling it with any args? Depending on the terminal settings and the env, the cwd may be different than you think also. Hard to say without seeing code though.

Comment: Thank you @StelioKontos for comment. Will add my code later.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33710264/edit) to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Thank you @JuanmiTaboada for comment. I add my code in original post. Please have a look and advise if any action. Thank you!

Comment: what is the use of `file.close()` and what is `next`

Comment: what is the reason to collect stuff in `All_DirName`

Comment: the thing to look for is `current working directory`

Comment: Hi @rioV8, 
1) the use of file.close() is to close open file and next is to focus the directory which naming includes 'twc' keyword as some directories don't contain this keyword.
2) Create list All_DirName to append directory naming

Based one above, may I know any observation/advice? Thank you

Comment: read up on `with`, `next` is a function but you don't use it as a function, it is a useless expression, `focus the directory` what does that mean, look what you do with `All_DirName` and then find out you don't need to store that list

Comment: is each directory name being split with '_' going to have exactly 4 pieces?  Do you need to consider the case where `Each_DirName_Split[3]` will cause an `IndexError`?  What if there are more than 4 pieces? - would 'twc' still be the 4th piece, or would it always be the last piece? 

And as rioV8 suggested, do you really want to be checking the directory the script file is in, or do you want to use the current working directory ? Or just prompt the user for a target directory so the script location doesn't matter?

Comment: Hi @rioV8 & nigh_anxiety, my intention is to put the script with target directories in one parent directory. Among target directories, each one can be split with '_' but not 4th pieces of each one is 'twc'. By doing this, I can filter out the directory whose 4th pieces split by '_' is 'twc' and is not 'twc'. Till now, no IndexError for my scenario, and it doesn't matter that split to more than 4 pieces or is the last piece. And could you tell me more why do I no need to use All_DirName? as I think it is necessary to store all directories naming which is stored with my script then can continue

Comment: Hi @nigh_anxiety, may I know how to show the underscore with ' ' in comment? My underscore in above comment is missing. Thank you.

Comment: you have to use backticks surrounding the `_`, underscore is used for italic in Markdown

Comment: use backticks to set any `code block`, or you can use backslash `\  ` to escape a single underscore, so `\_` == \_ ; otherwise markdown formatting uses underscores to mark something _in italics_.  Unfortunately backslash will also escape a backtick if it's the last character of a code block.....

Comment: 1) Between your two for loops, print the contents of your `All_DirName` array to stdout.
2) Temporarily remove the three lines near the end that open/write/close the file, and print that path to stdout also: `f'writing to file: {unitname}.txt'` Does the output match what you expect?

Comment: Hi @StelioKontos, I comment out the lines from `with open()` to `file.close()` and then add `f'writing to file: {unitname}.txt`. No error is observed but no output txt is generated actually.

Comment: I neglected to include the `print(f'...')` around the snippet in my previous comment; if you're still not getting anything written to stdout after fixing that syntax, then either execution flow is being blocked early on, or none of the conditions are being met to actually perform any logic on the files.

Comment: Also, note what @rioV8 said about `next`. Just glancing at your code, though, I really don't see a need for the last two lines to even be there. That's the whole point of a for loop.

Comment: @StelioKontos the last 3 lines are not needed

Comment: hi @StelioKontos, now stdout can show the message like: `writing to file: XXX.txt` but no txt files are generated acutally.

Comment: @rioV8 you are correct, since `with` handles closing the file for you; missed that on my precursors glance over it (pardon on the pun).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr;

Below is my how I would write your program while adhering to the original code's code flow. Explanation follows this, and I can update this answer if you provide more details.

To avoid confusion with paths, I would suggest simply requiring the user to provide it when running the script. The path provided by the user is the path that gets scanned, and is also the location of all text files the script creates; cwd and location of script file is then irrelevant.

```py
import os
import sys

# Usage:
# python Program.py <path>

def find_twc_folders(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for dir in dirs:
            parts = dir.split('_')
            if len(parts) == 4 and parts[3] == 'twc': # 'a_twc', 'a_b_c_twc_d', etc are skipped
                with open(os.path.join(path, dir[:-4] + '.txt'), 'a') as file: # substring with '_twc' removed
                    file.write(dir + '_K3\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        find_twc_folders(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        find_twc_folders(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

(EDIT: Changed to use the script's directory if program is called with no args).

### Folder setup:

Given the following directory setup, with your current working directory (cwd) in the VSCode terminal being one level above root:

```
PS C:\Users\there\source\repos\SO\75241788> tree /f
C:.
├───.vscode
└───root
    │   Program.py
    │
    ├───0_duplicate_path_twc
    ├───1a_one_two_three
    │   ├───0_duplicate_path_twc
    │   ├───2a_one_two_three
    │   │   ├───0_duplicate_path_twc
    │   │   ├───3a_one_two_three
    │   │   └───3b_one_two_twc
    │   └───2b_one_two_twc
    ├───1b_one_two_twc
    │   ├───2a_one_two_three
    │   ├───2b_one_two_three
    │   ├───2c_one_two_twc
    │   └───2d_one_two_twc
    └───1c_one_two_twc
```

A dry run gives us the following, after replacing the actual file operations with `print()`:

```
PS C:\Users\there\source\repos\SO\75241788> python root/Program.py
CurrentScriptDir: C:\Users\there\source\repos\SO\75241788\root
in "0_duplicate_path_twc" # <- in top level directory
in "1a_one_two_three"
in "1b_one_two_twc"
  open 1b_one_two.txt
    print: 1b_one_two_twc_K3\n
in "1c_one_two_twc"
  open 1c_one_two.txt
    print: 1c_one_two_twc_K3\n
in "0_duplicate_path_twc" # <- in sub level directory
in "2a_one_two_three"
# ...
```

In the current implementation, you are only pushing the directory name into your array, not the full path. A relative path that is unqualified will be considered rooted under the cwd by the OS, so your script will create all files at the location you see in your terminal to the left of the `>`.

Operating on folder names alone in this manner also means identical-named folders at different levels will result in multiple (duplicate) entries being added to the same file.

### Code fixes

The final `else` in your program is unnecessary, as your for loop does that anyways. As mentioned by @rioV8, `next` is being used incorrectly here also. Also pointed out by him, there is no need to close the file *in this case*, since `with` does that for you.

As it stands, removing the unneeded `All_DirName` array, removing the last 3 lines previously mentioned, moving your `join` operation inline, and prepending your filepaths with `CurrentScriptDir`, result in:

```py
import os

CurrentScriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(CurrentScriptDir):
    for each_dir in dirs:
        Each_DirName_Split = each_dir.split('_')
        # todo: check length > 3 first (or) compare last index instead
        if Each_DirName_Split[3] == 'twc':
            unitname = "_".join(Each_DirName_Split[0:-1])
            with open(os.path.join(CurrentScriptDir, unitname) + '.txt'), 'a') as file:
                file.write(each_dir + '_K3\n')
```

...And running it in the before-mentioned setup will walk all folders found in the folder the script is located in, saving all files to that same folder also.

EDIT: Added `os.path.join(CurrentScriptDir, ...)` in the previous code example to ensure the files are written next to the source program, regardless of current working directory.

Comment: Hi @Stelio Kontos, the new code based on original code is working but the output files are generated at the parent(upper) level.

Comment: That will save the files in your current working directory (the path visible in the terminal). My recommendation is to use the version I wrote at the top of my answer, that takes an arg when calling the script. Then the script location, and your current working directory no longer matter; whichever directory you want to scan, is where the files get saved to.

Comment: @Chris_L I edited my answer to save files to script location; see the revised code near the end.

Comment: Also added that as default behavior if ran without an arg for path in my code example in the "tl;dr;" section, which has basic error checking (unlike the last one)

Comment: hi @Stelio Kontos, thank you for detailing reply. I try with the version that you wrote at the top of answer and observe that output files can be generated at the same location with my script by running VSCode directly. 

But I want to further understand why do we need to use `if __name__ == '__main__':` and `sys.argv`? Is it because we don't want to care about script location or cwd and only focus on the directory that want to scan? If so, I assume `find_slc_folders(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))` is enough to acheive it? 
Sorry for late reply and many thanks!

Comment: That if statement is simply telling the python interpreter where to begin program execution when it runs your program. If your program has more than one function, it needs to be told where to start. If your script only contains one function, like your original code does, that is the implied entry point, since there are no other functions to choose from, and it is treated as main by default.

Comment: Yes, my last code example and in my answer simply concatenates the script location with the file name, to ensure it is saved where the script is located, not in your current working directory. My code example at the top of my answer does the same thing, only if the program is run without a scan path specified as an argument when running the script.

Comment: You also need the `os.path.join()` in the second to last line, which I mention in the last paragraph

Comment: Got it. Really thank you @Stelio Kontos for useful and detailing answer! Wish you and everyone have a good day!

Comment: Glad to help @Chris_L. If the answer resolved your question, marking it as accepted would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure @Stelio Kontos. Make this answer as accepted. Thank you.